# I get a error ""break" can be used only within a loop"

Tags: python

```
command = ""
while True: # if you use lower() you need to use lowercase letters for upper it's opposite
command = input("> ").lower()
if command == "start":
print("Car started...")
elif command == "stop":
print("Car stopped...") # (dry) don't repeat yourself
elif command == "help":
print("""
start - to start the car
stop - to stop the car
quit - to quit
""")
elif command == "quit":
break
else:
print("Sorry, i don't understand that.")
```

I want to get rid of this error "break" can be used only within a loop

Comment: In python indentation matters. Please show the code exactly as you're running it

Comment: [Here](https://www.scaler.com/topics/python/indentation-in-python/) is why getting your indentation right when asking for help on here is so important. `The reason why indentation is important in Python is because the indentation serves another purpose other than code readability. Python treats the statements that have the same indentation level (statements that have equal no of whitespaces before them) as a single block of code.`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The only way I can see that this error is happening is if the indentation of your code is wrong. Given that the `elif`, where the error is happening, is a part of a chain of `elif` statements, the whole block of code starting from `if` must be indented wrong, or else you'd be getting a different error.

Also, Python would throw an error if the `command = input("> ").lower()` line was not indented correctly. So, it seems that while that line is indented correctly, the rest of your code is not indented enough so as to be inside the `while` loop. Here is how I think your code should be indented, based on its contents:

```
command = ""
while True: # if you use lower() you need to use lowercase letters for upper it's opposite
    command = input("> ").lower()
    if command == "start":
        print("Car started...")
    elif command == "stop":
        print("Car stopped...") # (dry) don't repeat yourself
    elif command == "help":
        print("""
        start - to start the car
        stop - to stop the car
        quit - to quit
        """)
    elif command == "quit":
        break
    else:
        print("Sorry, i don't understand that.")
```

And here, below, is how I think your code was *incorrectly* indented when the error happened.

## Reminder: the code below is *NOT* correct and *will* give an error:

```
command = ""
while True: # if you use lower() you need to use lowercase letters for upper it's opposite
    command = input("> ").lower()
if command == "start":
    print("Car started...")
elif command == "stop":
    print("Car stopped...") # (dry) don't repeat yourself
elif command == "help":
    print("""
    start - to start the car
    stop - to stop the car
    quit - to quit
    """)
elif command == "quit":
    break
else:
    print("Sorry, i don't understand that.")
```